# Pass UITableView default PanGesture to another UIView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer, hittest

I have an `UITableView`, vertically covered over a `UIView` and that View have `UIPangestureRecognizer`. Now if user try to scroll tableView and if finger point have no cell I want second views panGesture response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass `UITableView` and override hitTest method.

-> if finger point have cell return `self`

-> else return nil or any other view that should response

Code:

```
class MyTableView: UITableView {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if indexPath(at: point) != nil {
            retrn self
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```